# How to run a docker pull request?

Tags: software-installation, docker

HI there so I found this program called Project Chrono and on their download page it is said that I need to pull it from docker, so I first installed docker using snap then proceeded to install it,

`sudo docker pull uwsbel/projectchrono:latest`

I tried running the command again and this is what I got

`latest: Pulling from uwsbel/projectchrono Digest: sha256:d3b2046318a08845189ee1241136a03d0b80242b5a50977b338afea375ec34be Status: Image is up to date for uwsbel/projectchrono:latest docker.io/uwsbel/projectchrono:latest`

but when I tried `sudo docker run projectchrono` it doesn't seem to find the files, as shown here

`Unable to find image 'projectchrono:latest' locally docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for projectchrono, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied. See 'docker run --help'.`

How can I run the program?

Link: https://projectchrono.org/download/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's literally right there in the Linux instructions on the linked page:

```
docker pull uwsbel/projectchrono:latest
```

You always need to pull before running (docker compose files make both steps easier), and the instructions tell you to pull before running, specifying the above command be run first.

You can also do this which should work:

```
docker run uwsbel/projectchrono:latest
```

This will tell Docker to run the image from the docker repository, and pull it if it's not available.  This should then execute it.

Bare-naming a docker image won't work if you don't use the full name author/program - otherwise it tries to test local images only.

---

There is a bug in the docker container itself, that needs upstream developers to update their Dockerfile to fix this.  The `locales` program is not installed, and the desired locale of `en_US.UTF-8` is NOT properly generated inside the docker image.  This results in these warnings:

```
/bin/bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
```

These are not necessarily *critical* errors, but there's nothing that we can do here to fix this - the upstream developers need to update their Dockerfile so that when the docker images are built for this the locale is properly set.

Comment: Okay, so I did that but when I tried to use `sudo docker run projectchrono` it says `Unable to find image 'projectchrono:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for projectchrono, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
See 'docker run --help'.`

Comment: Tru `docker run uwsbel/projectchrono` instead.  Because otherwise it won't know to pull from a repository image that was pulled down.

Comment: Hi there! I just ran the command and this is the output of the terminal `/bin/bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
`

Comment: That's an error in the container that the upstream developers need to fix, not a Docker issue on your system.  I confirmed this in testing on my end, the upstream devs need to update their Dockerfile to properly pull in `locales` into their 20.04 container and then GENERATE the `en_US.UTF-8` locale.  Which they don't do.  (I was expecting you to make a note about that).

Comment: Ohh thank you! Is there a way for me to have a workaround with that issue or should I just wait for the developers to fix their container?(Should I make this a separate question from this one?)

Comment: I'd contact the maintainers yourself and indicate the notes I made here.  I'm adding a section to my answer detailing this - unfortunately the only way they can fix this is actually UPDATING their docker image (which is nearly a year old at this point, so possibly unmaintained software?)

Comment: As for making this work, that's beyond the scope here, and they should provide documentation on actually *running* this - a straight `run` does nothing so you probably need to provide a specific path to execute.

Comment: Thank you again for your time! I'll try to reach out to the maintainers about this, have a great day!